# How to use a variable in a single command - Bash

Tags: linux, variables, samba

**ISSUE/QUESTION:**

How can I run this single command against each user; using $USER as the variable, listed in a text file, for example.

**WHY:**

I am developing a script that will check a user's password expiration date in Samba 3.x.

**THOUGHTS:**

I believe some form of the "FOR" function could work but I am having troubles making it effective and I am pressed for time.

```css
pdbedit -Lv $USER
```

(Note: This is not the complete command, just to simplify my problem area.)

I appreciate the help. I understand this is (should be) simple. Today I woke up on the wrong foot or something because I can't seem to connect the dots on much anything today...

Cheers

Comment: What's not working? We don't need the full command but some code context would be helpful.

Comment: I just have a text file of users. I am just a newbie but trying to learn..

My apologies, what do you mean by context? This is my command in full (which simply gives me the Epoch time that  user must change their password):

pdbedit -Lv justinb | grep -i "Password must change: " | echo "$PW_CHANGE_DATE"|awk '{print $5, $6, $7}' | date --date="$EPOCH_DATE_1" +%s

Comment: Why are you piping the output of grep to echo?  echo ignore its input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while read yourUser
do
  pdbedit -Lv $yourUser
done < users.txt
```

If users.txt has a blank line at the end that is fine, other wise you'll need another echo.

```
if [ $yourUser ]
then
  pdbedit -Lv $yourUser
fi
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I appreciate the your clarification! 

May I ask one more question, what does this line provide?:

done < users.txt

Is this the list I will check against?

Comment: @SeattleITguy That is the file it will read in. You could make it a cmd line argument if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have the array of users somehow. To loop through them you can use:

```
for user in "${USERS[@]}"
do
  pdbedit -Lv $user
done
```

Comment: I really like the code, unfortunately I don't have an array of users. I have a feeling that isn't a simple task. Unless you have a blueprint I can work off of?

Regardless thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

If the names are individual lines in a file:

```
while read USER; do pdbedit -Lv "$USER"; done < input.file
```

Comment: This looks pretty straightforward. Unfortunately I am also learning. I just want to clarify a couple things:

USER = my text file?
DO = For each line in the USER file?
done = What done 'done < input.file' perform?

Comment: The `< input.file` directs input from the file named `input.file` to the while loop, which is terminated by the string 'done'.  The while loop reads one line of its input into the variable 'USER', which holds the value read for that iteration of the loop.